# parse json in db2 with IDs field without TAG

Tags: db2

I have the following json Response and I'm trying to parse it, in DB2 v11.
The problem is that I'm not able to so.
The values 3e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad6bbb and 4e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd
are IDs and can have up to 60 in the response.
For me to do this, I would need like a kind of TAG for those IDs to be able to select them.
Then is there any ways to do this please ? Thank You -

```
{
    "3e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd": {
        "found": true,
        "signature": "FhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1NDE3MmFkNzc4MGU1Mjk2OD111111111",
        "sectors": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    "4e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd": {
        "found": false,
        "signature": "FhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1NDE3MmFkNzc4MGU1Mjk2O2222222",
        "sectors": []
    }
}
```

I tries this ...

```
INSERT INTO tablejson
SELECT '22222',
SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON('
{
    "3e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd": {
        "found": true,
        "signature": "MTY0NDI0MDA5NTUxOTozZTAwYTIwMWQ5ZDFiODk3MzJiZjhjN2EwMGFhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1NDE3MmFkNzc4MGU1Mjk2ODAzYWQ2MmNkOjEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsODpmOGU4YmNlN2I3OGZhZWY3NzVlNDNjM2ZhYzZjNWMzZGRkYzgyMzAzNjI5ZDhjYTc2MDFiODIzYTc0MDRjZWNl",
        "sectors": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8"
        ]
    },
    "4e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd": {
        "found": false,
        "signature": "MTY0NDI0MDA5NTUxOTo0ZTAwYTIwMWQ5ZDFiODk3MzJiZjhjN2EwMGFhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1NDE3MmFkNzc4MGU1Mjk2ODAzYWQ2MmNkOjphNTk2OTk1YjQ0ZTVmNGM4YTdiMGMxN2MzMzgyMmQyMzZkNDc2YTcyODA4ZTMyM2YxODI2Y2E5NWZjNjU2MWE0",
        "sectors": []
    }
}
')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1


SELECT ID,SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(jsonfield) AS JSON_INFO   FROM tablejson


SELECT JSON_VAL(jsonfield,'*.signature','s:1000')  FROM tablejson
```

But what yes is working is if I write directly the ID, but this is not helping a lot as the query should be generic.

```
SELECT JSON_VAL(jsonfield, '4e00a201d9d1b89732bf8c7a00aa7477ac7212354172ad7780e5296803ad62cd.found' ,'s:1000')
FROM tablejson
```

As the OUTPUT , I would like something like 3 fields

```
IDs                      found    signature
3e00a201d9d1b89732bf8...  true   FhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1ND...
4e00a201d9d1b89732bf8...  flase  FhNzQ3N2FjNzIxMjM1ND...
```

Thank You -

Comment: What is the query you have tried? Please share the desired outcome. Which Db2 version and platform (because they have different JSON support)?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Please add. Db2 has the old BSON storage format and a newer one. Look at functions like JSON_TABLE und JSON_QUERY: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-json-table